# How can number comparison be terminated in general way for macro parameter?

Tags: macros, tex-core, number

I'm wondering if there's a nice, generalized way to *terminate a number* which is given as a macro parameter either explicitly (as a number) or implicitly (as a register value or `\chardef`).  This would be for a conditional inside the macro, such as `\ifodd`, `\ifnum`, or `\ifcase`.

Minimal example:

```
\def\mymacro#1{%
\ifcase#1
first\or
second\else
other\fi}
```

I'd like `#1` to be any valid number or representation of a number, such as:
`123`
`\count@`
`\myval` (given `\chardef\myval=1`),
`\2` (given `\def\2{2}`), or even `` `\A ``.

I understand a space will terminate an explicit number value, but for other inputs the space can end up in front of "first". I've tried `\relax`, e.g., `\ifcase#1\relax`, but of course the `\relax` then ends up in front of "first" for some inputs. A percent character terminating the line isn't much help, or isn't a general solution, because the case statement would get messed up if the first true condition was a number instead of the word "first".

The only general solution I've come up with is to write the macro like this:

```
\def\mymacro#1{%
\ifcase\numexpr#1\relax
...
```

The above seems to work even if the input contains another `\numexpr`, but as a purist not wanting to rely on `etex`, I have a lingering feeling that there's a better way.  Suggestions?

Comment: I wound use `\count1=#1\relax` (for example) then use `\ifcase\count1 ...`.  It helps to be inside a group so as to not mess up `\count1` for other.

Comment: The assignment would make the macro non-expandable, but that may be okay in some cases.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

Using etex you can use

```
\numexpr#1\relax
```

as you say. For classic TeX I don't think it is possible other than by adding and removing a terminator such as

```
\def\hmm#1!{}

\def\mymacro#1{%
\expandafter\hmm\ifcase#1%
!zero\or
!one\else
!many%
\fi}


\mymacro{1}

\newcount\ccc \ccc=2
\mymacro\ccc

\mymacro{`a}

\bye
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, thanks.  I guess `numexpr` is the way to go.  I'm running `etex`, so clarity matters as much purity.  Now, if I only could make the leap from `\romannumeral` to `\expanded`...

Comment: @DanLevin all tex engines include etex (although disabled for the dvi based plain format) but really no need to avoid etex after 25+ years

Comment: You're right.  I avoid `etex` only occasionally when I'm feeling adventurous (or masochistic?).  Sometimes I wonder about performance differences with various macros, but those seem pretty unimportant nowadays.  It's mostly macro-writing _conventions_ I'm after so my code is understandable to others.  I think you do a good job with that.

Answer (score 3):

Via `\number` you can have TeX evaluate any valid(!) TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.
So without ε-TeX you can probably do:

```
\def\foo#1{#1}% *f*irst (argument) *o*f *o*ne.

\def\mymacro#1{%
\ifcase\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\number#1} %
first\or
second\else
other\fi}%
```

During evaluation via `\number`, triggered by `\expandafter`-chain,  the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity denoted by `#1` is terminated via closing brace `}` which in turn gets removed by `\foo` when evaluation via `\number` is finished.
During evaluation via `\ifcase` the number is already transformed to a sequence of explicit catcode-12(other)-digit-character-tokens, probably with a leading catcode-12-minus. That digit-sequence is terminated by an explicit space token which gets discarded in the course of `\ifcase`'s gathering of the tokens that form the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

Of course expansion of the tokens coming from `#1` needs to result in a set of tokens that forms a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity and nothing else.

---

Maybe ere long the question arises whether one can test whether a set of tokens expands to something that forms a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity.

As a set of tokens may form an expansion-based implementation of an algorithm, such a test, beneath other things, requires finding out whether an algorithm which is implemented in terms of TeX-tokens in a way where its carrying-out is driven by expansion only, terminates at all without error-messages.

Theoretically, one could perhaps(?) re-implement those aspects of the TeX-program that are relevant for expansion in TeX itself, and - instead of error messages - have tokens returned that represent error codes, and do some expansion-based evaluation thereof.

However, one would have to take care among other things that the subset of the TeX program implemented in TeX itself as TeX code cannot be changed to something else by the user input.

Even if one could do all this, one would only have dealt with the question of whether a terminating program terminates with an error message. The question whether a program terminates at all would not be dealt with.

I do not consider such not uninteresting theoretical considerations to be relevant in practice.

Comment: Good idea to use `\number` instead of `\numexpr.`  With your asterisks, I think you're saying that `\foo` could be the common `\@firstofone`.

Comment: @DanLevin `\numexpr` is to prefer if available. This way you cannot only pass valid TeX-<number>-quantities (like with `\number`) but also valid eTeX-<integer expr> probably trailed by <optional spaces and `\relax`>. If with `\number` you wish to have an <integer expr> calculated while eTeX-extensions are available, you need to turn the <integer expr> into a valid TeX-<number>-quantity by prepending `\numexpr` and appending `\relax`, which is more typing-work. | Yes, `\foo` could be the common `\@firstofone`. The asterisks denote the letters that form the acronym which forms the macro name.